# symfony2 dont send email

Tags: symfony, mailer

I'm developing a application in Symfony2
I have a command that will be run in a crontab

This is the command:

```
<?php
namespace project\projBundle\Service;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
class Sender {
    protected $em;
    protected $templating;
    protected $mailer;
    public function __construct($em, $templating,\Swift_Mailer $mailer) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->mailer = $mailer; }

    public function runSender() {
        $proj = $this->em->createQuery("query")->setMaxResults(20)->getResult();
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Contact enquiry from symblog')
            ->setFrom('...@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('...@gmail.com')
            ->setBody($this->templating->render('projectprojBundle:Others:emailNew.html.twig', array('proj' => $proj)));

        $this->mailer->send($message); } }
```

The parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: ~
    mailer_user: ...@gmail.com
    mailer_password: ...
```

In config_test:

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: false
```

But for some reason this not sending the email. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#type) emails are stored in files and you need to run the following command to send them:

```
console swiftmailer:spool:send
```

If you want to send emails directly without spooling them add `spool: { type: memory }` to your config file:

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: false
    spool: { type: memory }
```

More details can be found in the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html#spool-using-memory).